# How to handle new line characters when using COPY in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I have text that has the following form in my csv:

```
'0001'|'text1'|'\ntext2'|'text3'\n
```

However when I try to import the data into my postgres instance, it keeps breaking by thinking the first newline character is the start of a new line.  Is there an easy way to tell postgres to import the newline character into the field?

Comment: What `COPY` command are you using exactly? Is the `\n` literally `\n` or do you mean a literal newline character? What's the exact text of the error?

Comment: Perhaps because you forgot the delimiter `|` ?

Comment: Can you give more completed example ?

Answer (score 1):

If delimiters are explicitly set you avoid the trouble of special characters being interpreted, and instead are taken literally. The same thing can be said about quotes. The parser needs to know how to recognize strings to not interpret `\n` as a `newline`.

Here's the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html):

> Backslash characters () can be used in the COPY data to quote data
>   characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters.
>   In particular, the following characters must be preceded by a
>   backslash if they appear as part of a column value: backslash itself,
>   newline, carriage return, and the current delimiter character.

SO, you might have

```
COPY data FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'|' QUOTE E'\'';
```